# Search pattern from string

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm doing web scraping with [*BeautifulSoup*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) and I need to get a link which is in a *script* tag, so I use this

> soup.find(string=re.compile("https://link9876.net/index.php"))

this returns me the next string

```
"var link = [];
 link[0] = 'https://link1225.com/x/xxxxxx';
 link[1] = 'https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxxxxxxx';
 link[2] = 'https://link1356.com/index.php?xxxxxxxxx';
 ..."
```

(the position and number of the elements in the array changes every time)

But I only want to get "*[https://link9876.net/index.php*"](https://link9876.net/index.php*%22),
which is the best approach to resolve this?

Comment: It's a simple string search problem.  Find `link[1] =`, and grab everything up to the next single quote.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's not always `link[1] == my_link` if I execute the script again the order changes, and now can be `link[0] == my_link` or any other.

Comment: Please post the code to reproduce this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use another regular expression to extract any necessary links, for example:

```
import re

script_text = """var link = [];
 link[0] = 'https://link1225.com/x/xxxxxx';
 link[1] = 'https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxxxxxx1';
 link[2] = 'https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxxxxxx2';
 link[3] = 'https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxx3xxx';
 link[4] = 'https://link1356.com/index.php?xxxxx4xxx';
 link[5] = 'https://link1356.com/index.php?xxxxx4xxx';
 ..."""
 
for link in re.findall(r"'(https://link9876\.net/index\.php.*?)'", script_text):
    print(link)
```

Would give you:

```
https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxxxxxx1
https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxxxxxx2
https://link9876.net/index.php?xxxx3xxx
```